# How can I count when column A = "value1" and the matching row in column B = either "value1" or "value2"

Tags: google-sheets

Feels like a combination of `COUNTIF` plus `COUNTIFS` and I can't quite wrap my head around it.

I've used `=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(A:A,{"Value1", "Value2"})))` to count either or scenarios. `COUNTIFS` for counting when column A has a given value AND column B has another value.

But now I need: when A has a value1 AND B has EITHER value2 or value3.

I tried `=COUNTIF(range, "value1") - ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(range,{"value2", "value3"})))` but it didn't like it. I've been searching around for solutions but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can think as two different scenarios and sum them. Countifs when A is value 1 and B value 2 + countifs when A is value 1 and B value 3:

```
=countifs(A:A,"value 1",B:B,"value 2")+countifs(A:A,"value 1",B:B,"value 3")
```

I think that could work for you ;)

---

Another option: to make a query with one column and all the conditions you want, and count them
=counta(query(A:B,"select A where A = 'value 1' and B = 'value 2' or B = 'value 3'"))

Comment: I tried the countifs formula you provided. It definitely makes sense to me! But I got "array arguments to countfis are different sizes' error. I tried wrapping it in an arrayformula because that's worked in the past but it had no effect here. 

Not that it should matter but the ranges I'm actually using are: RangeA: M2:O17 and RangeB: P2:P17 for both countifs.

EDIT: I tried the Index(Sum formula below and it worked!

Comment: Ohhh, there were more than one column in one range. I didn't contemplate not tried that scenario, probably there's a way to adjust this, but I'm glad that Daniele's option already worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
=index(Sum((A:A="Value1")*(B:B="value2")+(A:A="Value1")*(B:B="value3")))
```

`Index()` works as `arrayformula()` here, without it the formula checks only the first cell.
`Sum()` finish the work.

**EDIT**
I think it can be better understood if written like this:

```
=Sum (index ((A:A = "Value1") * (B:B = "value2") + (A:A = "Value1") * (B:B = "value3")))
```

which in some cases can become like this:

```
=Sum ((1) * (1) + (1) * (0))
```

Comment: Hello @Daniele, could you explain me the logic behind this kind of expressions? Or where to read about it. Thanks!

Comment: I think it can be better understood if written like this:
`=Sum (index ((A:A = "Value1") * (B:B = "value2") + (A:A = "Value1") * (B:B = "value3")))` which in some cases can become like this: `=Sum ((1) * (1) + (1) * (0))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Daniele. The 1s and 0s and the interaction with + and * is the part I do understand of the logic. I don't get exactly how do Index and Sum interact in this logic, and the fact that you can change the order puzzled me more  Thanks for your time and knowledge!

Comment: `Index()` works as `arrayformula()` here, without it the formula checks only the first cell. `Sum()` finish the work.

Comment: OK, thanks!! (As far as I can see, it works only for strings, am I right?)

Comment: I use it everywhere

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks so much :D

Comment: @JRM Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) (tl;dr: please accept the answer that you consider is the solution that work best for you)

Comment: @Daniele From [answer]: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." Please consider to add the explanations that you gave in comments into the question body of your answer as comment are intented to be temporary.